# (LUA) Need help to send commands to a web server

Tags: lua

I have a robot and a vision system that can be manipulated through port 80 to receive commands. I'm unable to do so.

I've tried to mess around with Lua TCP socket communication but it is still too complex to what I'm able to understand (my brain is small). My robot has a plugin which allows me to manually send the commands on a web interface and that is the only way I know that works. I want to develop it into my main script code to allow it to run automatically.

This is part of the code for the vision system web interface

```
h1>Select Reference Object</h1><h3>Active reference object:&nbsp;Object 3</h3><br><form method="post" action="ReferenceObject"><h3>Available reference objects:&nbsp;<select name="bankList">
<option value="?refBank=1">Object 2</option>
<option value="?refBank=0">Object 1</option>
<option value="?refBank=2">Object 3</option>
<option value="?refBank=3">Object 4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="applyBank" value="Apply"/></h3></form>           


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the command from the vision system manual which when entered in the plugin or selected at the web interface works.
http://192.168.1.110/CmdChannel?sINT_1_1

Below is the code that completely does not work which I've tried.

```
tcp.client.connect("192.168.0.111", 80)
tcp.client.send_str_data("192.168.0.111", 80, "http://192.168.1.110/CmdChannel?sINT_1_1")
```

Comment: Where is the lua code you've tried?  Are you using the right tool for the job?  I know lua is great,  but it'd be easier in go.  However please post your missing lua code.   This html doesn't help

Comment: The robot programming language is based on LUA. The whole thing works for now because of the TCPIP / Ethernet format settings. The lua code I've tried is complete garbage :<

Comment: You want an http lua client not pure tcp.  You could call to curl command line and parse the result

Comment: I have a found a new command to send that has nothing to do with http. However, the rest of my program operation cannot be run. I'm referring to the robot program manual and tried ```tcp.client.connect("192.168.0.111", 2115)
tcp.client.send_str_data("192.168.0.111", 2115, "sINT1 1")```

Comment: Try this library.  https://daurnimator.github.io/lua-http/0.2/  or https://openresty.org/en/